# C pointer Definition Questions

Tags: c, pointers

I am quite confused about the concepts of the string literal and its pointer in `C`.

For example, if I want to define a pointer to a character, and :

```
char* s = "hello";

printf("%s\n",s); // this print "hello"
```

Because in C, strings are arrays of characters. So in my opinion, `char* = "hello"` should define a character pointer that points to the first element in the string (i.e. the memory address for 'h'). How it generates the whole string literal when printed?

Another example is when a char pointer is defined as:

```
void stringFunc(char strings[ROWS][COLS])
{   
    char* initial_p = strings;
}
```

It should be fine, because `strings` is a pointer and we can make a name (initial_p) of that pointer. However, gcc sticks that it's wrong and forces the correction to:

```
char* initial_p = *strings;
```

I can't figure out the reason. because `*strings` should be a dereference of the pointer, and should not be assigned to a pointer's name.

Comment: *"How it generates the whole string literal when printed?"* `printf` repeatedly increments it to print every character, until it hits a null char. *"gcc sticks that it's wrong"* The pointer type is different. You have a pointer to an array (to `char[COLS]`), not to a single char.

Answer (score 2):

> Because in C, strings are arrays of characters. So in my opinion, `char* = "hello"` should define a character pointer that points to the first element in the string (i.e. the memory address for 'h'). How it generates the whole string literal when printed?

It generates the entire string literal when printed because the `%s` format specifier for `printf` outputs a string given a pointer to its first character. It could also have been defined to dereference and output the first character or to print out the pointer in hex, but it wasn't defined that way because this behavior is more useful. It's useful to have an easy way to output a string, and the logical way to specify that string is by a pointer to its first character because that's the C way of doing it.

> I can't figure out the reason. because *strings should be a dereference of the pointer, and should not be assigned to a pointer's name.

In this case, `strings` is a double array type. It's just not a `char *` and so can't be assigned to a variable of that type.

Comment: Obligatory nitpick that `strings` is a pointer rather than array, because of being a function parameter.

Comment: "`strings` is a double array type "--> `strings` is a pointer to array `COLS` of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

> How it generates the whole string literal when printed?

**From C11:**

> s
>
> If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to
> the initial element of an array of character type. **Characters from
> the array are written up to (but not including) the terminating null
> character**. If the precision is specified, no more than that many bytes
> are written.

So, `printf` looks for a null-byte when no length modifier is specified as a signal to stop. Otherwise, it continues printing until it sees a null-byte in memory or the system realizes it's accessing memory out of bounds — in which case you will most likely get a segmentation violation signal, but nearly anything can happen as the behaviour is undefined.